# How to reproduce the following 3 figures

Tags: diagrams, logic

Does anyone know the code for Figures 1, 2, and 3 of Claude Shannon's paper "[A Symbolic Analysis of Relay and Switching Circuits](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/greatworks/shannon38.pdf)"?

[image]

I have seen "[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)" and the "[Circuitikz – Draw electrical networks with TikZ](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf)" package, but I can't really see how to produce the fork-like and multi-map-like line-with-circle ending in both directions that is very simple in essence, but without a clear construct symbol or code, from what I can see at present time.

[image]

Comment: these are just lines and circldes you could use tikz or no package at all and use picture mode and `\line` for the lines and `\circle` and `\circle*` for the white and black circles.

Answer (score 4):

`picture`, Ti*k*Z, Metapost versions for Figure 3. All three variants can be scaled as needed.

Two small disclaimers:

- There is no fancy automation stuff going on here about placement and centering of the labels in the figures, it's just a bit of tweaking by hand.
- The Metapost version does not center correctly on the page for me. I'm not very experienced with Metapost yet, so I haven't been able to figure out why.

---

## Result

The Metapost version is scaled differently than the other two here. This can be adjusted, as said. I've added some `lipsum` text around it to see how it would look on the page; obviously this is not strictly required.

[image: picture of result]

---

## Code

I've put all three in a single document. If you're going to go with the Metapost version, compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mflogo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\setlength\unitlength{0.5cm} % Adjust as needed
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(5,3)(2.5,0.5)
        \put(0,2){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(1,2){\circle*{0.1}}
        \put(1,2){\line(0,1){1}}
        \put(1,2){\line(0,-1){1}}
        \put(1,3){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(1,1){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(2.05,3){\circle{0.1}}
        \put(2.95,3){\circle{0.1}}
        \put(2.05,1){\circle{0.1}}
        \put(2.95,1){\circle{0.1}}
        \put(4,2){\line(0,1){1}}
        \put(4,2){\line(0,-1){1}}
        \put(3,3){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(3,1){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(4,2){\circle*{0.1}}
        \put(4,2){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(2.41,3.25){$x$}
        \put(2.41,0.55){$y$}
        \put(5.2,1.9){$=$}
        \put(5.65,2){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(6.70,2){\circle{0.1}}
        \put(7.60,2){\circle{0.1}}
        \put(7.65,2){\line(1,0){1}}
        \put(6.85,2.25){$x \cdot y$}
    \end{picture}
\caption{Interpretation of multiplication. (\texttt{picture} environment)}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5] % adjust as needed
        \draw (0,0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (2, 1) 
                       (1, 0) -- (1,-1) -- (2,-1)
                       (3, 1) -- (4, 1) -- (4, 0) -- (5,0)
                       (3,-1) -- (4,-1) -- (4, 0)
                       (2.1, 1) circle (0.1)
                       (2.1,-1) circle (0.1)
                       (2.9, 1) circle (0.1)
                       (2.9,-1) circle (0.1)
                       (2.5, 1.3) node {$x$}
                       (2.5,-1.3) node {$y$}
        ;
        \fill (1,0) circle (0.1)
              (4,0) circle (0.1)
        ;
        \node at (5.25,-0.02) {$=$};
        \draw (5.75,0) -- ++(1,0)
               ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0)
               (6.85,0) circle (0.1)
               (7.65,0) circle (0.1)
               (7.25,0.3) node {$x \cdot y$}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Interpretation of multiplication. (Ti\emph{k}Z version) }
\end{figure}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{mplibcode}
        u=10mm; % scaling
        beginfig(1);
            draw (0,0) -- (1u,0) -- (1u,1u) -- (2u,1u);
            draw          (1u,0) -- (1u,-1u) -- (2u,-1u);

            draw (3u,1u) -- (4u,1u) -- (4u,0) -- (5u,0);
            draw (3u,-1u) -- (4u,-1u) -- (4u,0);

            filldraw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (1u,0);
            draw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (2.05u,1u);
            draw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (2.05u,-1u);
            draw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (2.95u,1u);
            draw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (2.95u,-1u);
            filldraw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (4u,0);

            label.top(btex $x$ etex,(2.5u,1u));
            label.bot(btex $y$ etex,(2.5u,-1u));
            label(btex $=$ etex,(5.25u,0));

            draw (5.5u,0) -- (6.75u,0);
            draw (7.75u,0) -- (8.75u,0);
            draw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (6.8u,0);
            draw fullcircle scaled (0.1u) shifted (7.7u,0);
            label.top(btex $x \cdot y$ etex,(7.25u,0));
        endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
    \caption{Interpretation of multiplication. (\MP{} version) }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. I went along with the Tikz withouth lualatex output, but in the meanwhile, I was caught by several log error in relation to some accents-related problem, and I could not respond. Indeed, I´m not yet working again on the Project file, and trying to solve the issue... many thanks again

Comment: @alpenwasser - the note at the bottom of page 2 of [the mplib user notes](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf) explains what to do to get mplib centered.